# Mixin of abstract class

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, mixins

I would like to create a mixin. I use for that the following syntax :

```
abstract class NumberGenerator {
    abstract int32(): number;
    abstract seed(s: number): void;
    perc() {
        return this.int32() / 4294967296.0;
    }
    next(cases: number) {
        return Math.floor(this.perc() * cases);
    }
}
export default <Generator extends typeof NumberGenerator>(generator: Generator) =>
class ForcedGenerator extends generator {
    private numbers: number[];
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
        const numbers = args.shift() as number[];
        super(...args);
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }
    int32() {
        return this.numbers.length ? this.numbers.shift() : super.int32();
    }
}
```

It works pretty well and allows me to use the type `ForcedGenerator(MyGenerator)` .

The problem occurs when the `NumberGenerator` root class is abstract and:

- Show an error as `ForcedGenerator` does not have a definition of `seed` (an abstract function of `NumberGenerator` )
- Has an error on `super.int32()` -> "Abstract method 'int32' in class 'NumberGenerator' cannot be accessed via super expression."

Basically, one error per abstract method.

Is there an extended version of `Generator extends typeof NumberGenerator` that specifies "a non-abstract inheritor of `NumberGenerator`" ?

Note: `Generator extends new(...args: any[])=> NumberGenerator` does not solve the situation.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to map types so as to just "de-`abstract`" members without also "de-methoding" them (see [ms/TS#35416](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35416) among others).  So you can write [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoMvPN) but the compiler is unhappy that you're apparently overriding an instance property with a method.  You can `//@ts-ignore` that and it [seems to work](https://tsplay.dev/mqy4dm), but I wouldn't recommend it.  Instead you should probably just manually describe the type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2vRjw). (continues)

Comment: (see prev comment) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does - I ended up doing such after writing here, while wondering if there was no automated "de-abstract" way and seeing it as a patch.

Answer (score 1):

You'd like to transform the instance type of

```
declare abstract class NumberGenerator {
    abstract int32(): number;
    abstract seed(s: number): void;
    perc(): number;
    next(cases: number): number;
}
```

to something like

```
interface ConcreteNumberGenerator {
    int32(): number;
    seed(s: number): void;
    perc(): number;
    next(cases: number): number;
}
```

That is: strip the `abstract` modifier from the members, while maintaining the shape of the methods.

---

Unfortunately there is currently no way in TypeScript to programmatically control certain attributes of class members, such as whether a member is [`abstract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members), or [`private`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private), or [`protected`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#protected), or a [method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#methods) (as opposed to a function-valued property).

When a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) transforms a class instance type, it strips all of these attributes from the resulting type.   See [microsoft/TypeScript#35416](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35416) for a feature request asking to allow these to be preserved.

---

So, you can use an "identity" mapped type like

```
type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
```

and it will strip `abstract` as desired.  That gets you pretty close.  Unfortunately it also turns all your methods into function-valued properties:

```
type AlmostConcreteNumberGenerator = Id<NumberGenerator>;
/* type AlmostConcreteNumberGenerator = {
    int32: () => number;
    seed: (s: number) => void;
    perc: () => number;
    next: (cases: number) => number;
} */
```

This is close to what you want, but unfortunately TypeScript will not allow you to override a function-valued property with a method:

```
export default <G extends
  new (...args: any) => AlmostConcreteNumberGenerator
>(generator: G) =>
  class ForcedGenerator extends generator {
    private numbers: number[];
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      const numbers = args.shift() as number[];
      super(...args);
      this.numbers = numbers;
    }
    int32() { // error!
      // Class 'Id<NumberGenerator>' defines instance member property 'int32', 
      // but extended class 'ForcedGenerator' defines it as instance member function.(2425)
      return this.numbers.length ? this.numbers.shift()! : super.int32();
    }
  }
```

There are various feature requests asking for an improvement here, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#48125](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48125).  A [comment by the TS team dev lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48125#issuecomment-1059621624) indicates that maybe the solution here is to just allow methods to override function-valued properties if the overridden prop is from a mapped type.  Right now, though, this is not part of the language.

---

It's up to you how to proceed from here.  The error above doesn't seem to actually affect anything if you ignore it, so you could just [`//@ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) it:

```
export default <G extends
  new (...args: any) => AlmostConcreteNumberGenerator
>(generator: G) =>
  class ForcedGenerator extends generator {
    private numbers: number[];
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      const numbers = args.shift() as number[];
      super(...args);
      this.numbers = numbers;
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    int32() {
      return this.numbers.length ? this.numbers.shift()! : super.int32();
    }
  }
```

But while convenient, `//@ts-ignore` is risky, since all it does is suppress an error from being displayed. It doesn't fix the underlying problem.  Often errors in one part of your code can have surprising effects elsewhere, so `//@ts-ignore` will just make this sort of thing difficult to debug.  As I said: in this case, the error doesn't *seem* to have effects elsewhere, but unless you're certain about that I'd be wary of this approach.

---

Personally, since there's no foolproof programmatic approach, I'd recommend just writing out `ConcreteNumberGenerator` manually as shown above.  You can even make this easier by having the interface extend `NumberGenerator`, so you only need to override the `abstract` bits:

```
interface ConcreteNumberGenerator extends NumberGenerator {
  int32(): number;
  seed(s: number): void;
}

export default <Generator extends
  new (...args: any) => ConcreteNumberGenerator
>(generator: Generator) =>
  class ForcedGenerator extends generator {
    private numbers: number[];
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      const numbers = args.shift() as number[];
      super(...args);
      this.numbers = numbers;
    }
    int32() {
      return this.numbers.length ? this.numbers.shift()! : super.int32();
    }
  }
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&target=99#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgcgVwLYgFMoBxAgOyOAgHsoEBvAKAQVEhngQEsyIBmAEwAKAJQAuBGTyEoAbmatw0OIjAECAEyFgJU-EXEIAbtS4b5LAA5FYohgpZQCEbFDIIIACy5gAdD35hEQQAegQAFgEATnCogDYAdmi43wAGCwQAXwUKAA8IIVg0Ah1JaQN7FkdnV3cAWSpPXwAzZGpaIS8fX2soW2CAKiRisBEM7OzGDQIUYCdFdhUkVHQscpJyShooAUqF5U4AwVFddYy2A9V1LVK9GUMTMwze-tP9ORyCfMKRt-u-ojySYBIjNOAEBAAYWoZFgTggBBw71IFBg2z2RyCAI+LDUmm02IepnMCheJzK7wyeQKRTUt3WhjugMYkwgAE9rAgAJIaAA8ABUAHwIAC8DAQAG0ANLcdwAawIbOozQQ-IAuhJ+dK1VlGOzOQBBZC4aiQaGw+GI9Yora0UXcvlImQ2tG0QXyEJDfUQo0ms0wuHOK3IzauuhipgsTESOwi4VMnEIPEaGP097BOPGYnPGwxjPxs6ffIx2klQmiguUlkIAYhRj12AwyAIZpcXKpe284gIL4IsgaMCfADuCCEvnHcwA5qVgGQ2fmHbynUQXVQ3YxBUJJ6G11AJMR8wpZqsAGK0WCaVfo3vkAcIbeo3d7KxQLhGKgQhNpmQStUZFiNmQ7DYPAHTjr4U4znOv7BJGVQAU2iBfvakG+GA3jNAUwRoBSP5-g4VRgNgvRjhOUDTmMBEsF0fjIWKX7-rq8EhGEYAAAIQGAAC0XCTmQtAEARmJ2PQoRhEQUC0AAhFRYlQisGAAOQ8ku1o7tsgqKQg0ythQGA8JAs4XgguAEO8CCWJJvTsggimYopAA0CCySxCAgNgiA3v2mjLGgSlnn0l7qbQWk6TwJTcIgOEGRARkQqZ5nNNgsIQFwMK+EIAiRAArCIsnwrUHjeLR6x+Mg5CTl4CAAPxFd0X5oRhWFSQgEhEb0-i8MclHwdkLCTIBzatrkACMnbdl5A7DqO4GQRIs7zhWi7Lhsj4aRuW7BXuCAHhWR4KQgAUXhoV52pNGAPradBwS+b4frhRDfkQv6MYN0AgdspEQeRUFsjBz5VG9D1QBgYqoehXCYXYOEJi9sntUQX2QT18F1SV7yg8DYCMX1VSuRx3G8fxThCV1QQA9ULhuGjvgNeVZCVZ4NU0w1ENQyILVtcRRCdYEog4wokyMCCUBgsZ5qBgiK2nXQ51rCGa12nBwmMoWuLXASwNEk8LINohLZtrsYpdltPb5Leg4sBQI5Iz981zguEuWtLW0bZdYb7lth4AQdR1BYrsvm-2F2mzdFmvu+CJY9icPwW9UAfWBZHTvbf1qrBslA3RrA-Y1kNYawGCw-hqNJtzUC2xRjHUcVtOlfaDEEbjUZkyJ+U1NTNF1xjvj04zzNd6zTWiJzZcdSrAv9fWQA)